# How do I use BeautifulSoup4 to get ALL text before <br> tag into a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tags

I'm trying to extract postcode and suburbs of sydney as dataframe by scraping a website

I've located the corresponding tag in beautifulsup but am not able to finish the process

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://data.mongabay.com/igapo/australia/postcodes/sydney-numeric.html'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html5lib')

table = soup.find_all('table')[10]

rows = table.find_all('td')[2]

for br in rows.find_all("br"):
    br.replace_with("\n")

parsedText = rows.get_text()
```

I'm expecting a dataframe such as:

```py
postcode suburbs
2000 Australia Square Post Office
2000 Circular Quay
2000 Clarence Street Post Office
...
```

thank you for your help

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to finish the process"? What is the current output, and what is your expected output?

Comment: Can't replicate the problem - I'm getting your expected output; what's your current output?

Comment: mmh i got this string too but i would like to transform it into a pandas dataframe. how can i proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat verbose method. bs4 4.7.1

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
​
url = 'https://data.mongabay.com/igapo/australia/postcodes/sydney-numeric.html'
r = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
codes = []
names = []
​
for line in soup.select_one('h1:contains("Postal codes") ~ font [size="2"]').text.split('\n'):
    if line[:4]:
        codes.append(line[:4]), names.append(line[5:])
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(codes, names)), columns = ['code', 'name'])

​
```

Comment: did you try these?

Answer (score 0):

You did pretty much all the work! You just have to read it in correctly.

```
from io import StringIO
import re

pd.read_csv(StringIO(parsedText), sep= r'(?<=\d) ', header = None, engine = 'python')
```

So we need to use StringIO to make your text readable by `pd.read_csv`, then we can do some regex to define our separator.

`r'(?<=\d) '` looks for a space (notice the space after ')' ) if there is a digit preceding it.